# An SQLAlchemy analogue to Rails' Model#find

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

In Rails I'm used to calling `Model.find(id)` to fetch a record from a database.

Now in SQLAlchemy I'm using `db_session.query(Model).filter(Model.id == id)`. Does SQLAlchemy have something similar as Rails' find method?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean a primary key, there is `Query.get()` in the [API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get):

```
db_session.query(Model).get(id)
```

Comment: This is probably as close to the same if you're looking from a syntactical point of view, although I believe Rails' `find()` throws an exception if the record is not found found, while SQLAlchemy's `get()` returns `None` if not found. If you want an exception raised, you should use SQLAlchemy's [`one()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) (although that means using the `filter()` method).

Comment: This is a step closer. I actually was looking for a class method that instantiates an object. In the end I extended Base with a find method, works!